# How do I make the squares all equal in size, despite their text content?

Tags: html, css-grid

[Please see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wizQP.jpg). [Image 2 after adjusting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vosWq.jpg) I'm trying to make each section the same size (a proper square like the "h1" box) but it seems the text content in each box is affecting this and maybe something else missing from CSS?

Each square is a button as I've added JS modals to each.

I have tried playing around with padding but i don't think this is the problem.

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p id="modalText"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <div class="periodic-table">
      <div class="empty-space-1"></div>
      <div class="empty-space-2"></div>

      <button class="open-modal periodic-element one" data-id="h1">
        <div class="periodic-table-inner">
          <div class="title">h1</div>
          <div class="desc">Large Heading</div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="style">
        <div class="periodic-element one">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Style</div>
            <div class="desc">Styling</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="anchor">
        <div class="periodic-element two">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">A</div>
            <div class="desc">Anchor</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="comment">
        <div class="periodic-element three">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">!-></div>
            <div class="desc">Comment</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="svg">
        <div class="periodic-element three">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Svg</div>
            <div class="desc">Svg Image</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="ul">
        <div class="periodic-element four">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Ul</div>
            <div class="desc">Unordered List</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="br">
        <div class="periodic-element four">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Br</div>
            <div class="desc">Line Break</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="li">
        <div class="periodic-element one">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Li</div>
            <div class="desc">List</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="ol">
        <div class="periodic-element one">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Ol</div>
            <div class="desc">Ordered List</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="img">
        <div class="periodic-element three">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Img</div>
            <div class="desc">Image</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="nav">
        <div class="periodic-element three">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Nav</div>
            <div class="desc">Navigation</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="em">
        <div class="periodic-element two">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Em</div>
            <div class="desc">Emphasized</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="div">
        <div class="periodic-element two">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Div</div>
            <div class="desc">Groups Elements</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="link">
        <div class="periodic-element two">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Link</div>
            <div class="desc">External Link</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="i">
        <div class="periodic-element four">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">I</div>
            <div class="desc">Italic</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="u">
        <div class="periodic-element four">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">U</div>
            <div class="desc">Underlined</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="b">
        <div class="periodic-element four">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">B</div>
            <div class="desc">Bold text</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="col">
        <div class="periodic-element two">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Col</div>
            <div class="desc">Column Properties</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="data">
        <div class="periodic-element two">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Data</div>
            <div class="desc">M-R Data</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="body">
        <div class="periodic-element three">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Body</div>
            <div class="desc">Main Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="dfn">
        <div class="periodic-element three">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Dfn</div>
            <div class="desc">Defined term</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="title">
        <div class="periodic-element two">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <div class="desc">Tab Title</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="meta">
        <div class="periodic-element two">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Meta</div>
            <div class="desc">Metadata</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="abbr">
        <div class="periodic-element one">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Abbr</div>
            <div class="desc">Abbreviation</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="form">
        <div class="periodic-element four">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Form</div>
            <div class="desc">Form for User</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="h6">
        <div class="periodic-element four">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">h6</div>
            <div class="desc">Small Heading</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="main">
        <div class="periodic-element three">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Main</div>
            <div class="desc">Main Content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="html">
        <div class="periodic-element one">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Html</div>
            <div class="desc">Root HTML</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="p">
        <div class="periodic-element three">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">P</div>
            <div class="desc">Paragraph</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <button class="open-modal" data-id="href">
        <div class="periodic-element three">
          <div class="periodic-table-inner">
            <div class="title">Href</div>
            <div class="desc">URL</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  background: #000000;
  font-family: "poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-title {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 11px #0fa, 0 0 20px #0fa, 0 0 23px #0fa, 0 0 25px #0fa,
    0 0 37px #0fa;
}

.html {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0 0 11px #0fa, 0 0 20px #0fa, 0 0 23px rgb(255, 0, 0),
    0 0 25px rgb(255, 0, 0), 0 0 37px rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.periodic-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.periodic-element {
  padding: 4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: default;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.periodic-element .periodic-table-inner {
  background: #202e38;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  transition: inherit;
}

.periodic-element .title {
  font: 700 20px "poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0.3em 0 0;
  transition: 0.8s ease 600ms;
}

.periodic-element .desc {
  font: 500 12px "poppins", sans-serif;
  margin-top: -0.2em;
}

.periodic-element:hover {
  transform: scale(1.12);
  z-index: 10;
}

.periodic-element:hover .periodic-table-inner {
  background: transparent;
}

.periodic-element:hover .title,
.periodic-element:hover .desc {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #222;
}

.peroidic-element:hover:after {
  top: 105%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.periodic-element {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.one {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #f3f9a6 0%, #cbc634 100%);
}

.one .title,
.one .desc {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f3f9a6, #cbc634);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.four {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #fa7f72 0%, #ffc171 100%);
}

.four .title,
.four .desc {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fa7f72, #ffc171);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.two {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #37cfdc 0%, #5a88e5 100%);
}

.two .title,
.two .desc {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#37cfdc, #5a88e5);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.three {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #58ac30 0%, #a7df62 100%);
}

.three .title,
.three .desc {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#58ac30, #a7df62);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.empty-space-1 {
  grid-column: 3 / span 4;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.empty-space-2 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.desc {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

button {
  background: none;
}

/* The Modal */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 3; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```css
.periodic-element {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.open-modal {
  padding: 0;
}
```

I created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lefede/pen/QWVXQwb) to check it

Comment: Thanks for this, it is a little better now but still doesn't use up whole space. I'll add another image.

Comment: I edited it. Sorry I didn't see it at first @Katie